# Fetch data greater than 1 hour

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to fetch all data from my database that were created greater than 1 hour ago. I have the following code, Pls point me to the right direction.

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `merge_ago` <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

My DB column type is DATETIME. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is wrong with the results you are getting?

Comment: Getting some empty results and there are older data in the DB

Answer (score 0):

You current `where` clause gives you records whose `merge_ago` is *older* than 1 hour before the current timestamp.

From the comments, you seem to want records that are *less than one hour old*. For this, you need to invert the inequality:

```
where merge_ago >= now() - interval 1 hour
```

Note that I replaced `date_sub()` with a regular substraction against a literal interval. There is usually no need to use `date_sub()` (and sister function `date_add()`) in MySQL, which supports date/interval arithmetics.

Comment: No, I want data greater than 1 hour old.

Comment: @GMB please close duplicates rather than generate new redundant content on this site.  You have been here long enough to identify basic/duplicate questions. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397526/2943403

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `merge_ago` > date_add(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR);
```

Comment: To format lines of code, you can: add 4 spaces before the line, highlight your code then press Ctrl+K, or highlight and click the code formatting icon in the toolbar.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it